# How do I get wxFormBuilder to allow me to add a status bar

Tags: wxformbuilder

I am using wxFormBuilder 3.10.1 and want to add a status bar to an existing fairly complex dialog.  No matter what I do, I get the message "Impossible to create the object. Did you forget to add a sizer/parent object or turn on/off an AUI management?"  (I've tried adding it at multiple levels in the sizer hierarchy.)

I've had no luck searching for an answer using any of the obvious keywords.  Any suggestions?